# Get profile picture of a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, image

There seems to be a change in the API. It's been a few days it's not possible to access pages' profile picture anymore. You could usually do that by querying:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/picture
```

Any idea on how to do that now?

Comment: One issue is that it doesn't work for users who post as a Facebook Page. @user658042 has the answer right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all: Works for me. At least the sample link from the documentation¹ and a few others.

It might be possible that the visibility of a picture is restricted, in that case you have to request the picture with a proper access token in the url. Use this format:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/picture?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE
```

See [the doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), under [Authorization].

¹ Sample link: http://graph.facebook.com/DoloresPark/picture

Comment: This works for me, but it has to be modified to be `https` instead of the claimed `http`

Comment: The size is very small, how can we give custom size?

Comment: To adjust the size, append ?type=large|normal|small|square to the request

Comment: Dont do this if you want to use this URL in the HTML! Your token is like a password, leaking that is really bad

Answer (score 7):

you can also get the info via an app id if you want to find the picture with an facebook app request.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/picture?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE
```

Comment: This is the better answer b/c the app ID can be made public (eg can appear in your HTML). It's not a good practice to use the page's access token in public facing HTML as shown in the other answer.